# perf cycles not supported

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, kvm, perf

I am trying to use perf for profiling in a Linux virtual machine. However, I am receiving the following output:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ perf stat -d ls /
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  vagrant  var

 Performance counter stats for 'ls /':

          1.063002      task-clock (msec)         #    0.408 CPUs utilized
                13      context-switches          #    0.012 M/sec
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec
               101      page-faults               #    0.095 M/sec
   <not supported>      cycles
   <not supported>      instructions
   <not supported>      branches
   <not supported>      branch-misses
   <not supported>      L1-dcache-loads
   <not supported>      L1-dcache-load-misses
   <not supported>      LLC-loads
   <not supported>      LLC-load-misses

       0.002608020 seconds time elapsed
```

Many of the interesting values seem not to be supported. I have tried this on both kvm and virtualbox guests with the virtualbox guests tried on both Linux and Mac OS. My online readings suggest that perf is supported inside kvm guests. So this is really puzzling me. What could be going wrong?